# Use Protocol with associatedtype as a Type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I have the protocol like this

```
protocol ViewBuilder {
    associatedtype In
    associatedtype Out
    
    func build(_ data: In?) -> Out?
}
```

I have the concrete struct like these. **TitleTypeView** and **ButtonTypeView** have the same super class.

```
struct HeaderTitleBuilder: ViewBuilder {
    func build(_ data: DataSource?) -> ViewFactory? {
        guard let data = data else { return nil }
        return TitleTypeView(data)
    }
}

struct HeaderButtonBuilder: ViewBuilder {
    func build(_ data: DataSource?) -> ViewFactory? {
        guard let data = data else { return nil }
        return ButtonTypeView(data)
    }
}
```

I have to combine the Builders struct into HeaderBuilder

```
struct TestStruct {
    func create() {
        HeaderBuilder(titleBuilder: HeaderTitleBuilder()
                                           , seeallBuilder: HeaderButtonBuilder())
    }
}

struct HeaderBuilder
{
    private(set) var titleBuilder: some ViewBuilder = HeaderTitleBuilder()
    private(set) var buttonBuilder: some ViewBuilder = HeaderButtonBuilder()
}
```

I got this error

> Cannot convert value of type 'HeaderTitleBuilder' to expected argument type 'some ViewBuilder'

> Cannot convert value of type 'HeaderButtonBuilder' to expected argument type 'some ViewBuilder'

So I try to use protocol as a generic constraint

```
struct HeaderBuilder <T: ViewBuilder>
where T.In == DataSource, T.Out == ViewFactory {

    private(set) var titleBuilder: T = HeaderTitleBuilder()
    private(set) var buttonBuilder: T = HeaderButtonBuilder()
}
```

**DataSource** and **ViewFactory** are all protocols without associatedtype.

I got this error.

> Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'T' ('HeaderTitleBuilder' vs. 'HeaderButtonBuilder')

I guess the compiler is using HeaderTitleBuilder and HeaderButtonBuilder to infer the type of T. But it is not what I want. I just need to T to be a protocol type that allows me to pass any Builder type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ViewBuilder` is a protocol, when you try make `T` a concrete type, it creates a conflict whether that type `T` is `HeaderTitleBuilder` or `HeaderButtonBuilder`. `T` cannot be both at the same time.

You can instead make both have a separate generic parameter, e.g,:

```
struct HeaderBuilder<TitleBuilder: ViewBuilder, ButtonBuilder: ViewBuilder> where TitleBuilder.In == DataSource, TitleBuilder.Out == ViewFactory, ButtonBuilder.In == DataSource, ButtonBuilder.Out == ViewFactory {
    private(set) var titleBuilder: TitleBuilder
    private(set) var buttonBuilder: ButtonBuilder
}
```

Comment: Since the .In and .Out is always the same, Is there a way to make it general ?

Comment: @benoitcn You can't really get any more general, since `TitleBuilder<DataSource, ViewFactory>` and `ButtonBuilder<DataSource, ViewFactory>` are fundamentally different types. `titleBuilder` and `buttonBuilder` are also separate variables too, so you always know the type at compile-time anyway.

Comment: Any suggestions that how should I refactor this code?

Comment: @benoitcn Given the limit code, throw out the generics which are - in this case - useless (since they both have the same `ViewBuilder` associated types). I recommend you don't use generics unless you need to as they make code more complicated. Otherwise, this appears fine.